# Weight factors by eigenvalues from PROC FACTOR in SAS?

Tags: statistics, sas, factor-analysis

I am trying to weight the factors from PROC FACTOR by their eigenvalues, but am having some difficulty. I have a solution, but it seems to me that there should be a more direct way to do this.

```
** Get factors and eigenvalues;
ods output Eigenvalues=MyEigenVals
proc factor data=MyData method=principal out=MyData;
    var X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6;
run;
ods output close;

** Transpose the eigenvalues;
proc transpose data=MyEigenVals out=MyEigenVals(drop=_NAME_) prefix=eigenval;
    id Number;
    var Eigenvalue;
run;

** Merge the data and fill down the eigenvalues;
data MyData;
    merge MyData MyEigenVals;
    retain E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        E1 = eigenval1;
        E2 = eigenval2;
        E3 = eigenval3;
        E4 = eigenval4;
        E5 = eigenval5;
        E6 = eigenval6;
    end;
    ** weight each factor by its eigenvalue;
    factor1 = factor1 * E1;
    factor2 = factor2 * E2;
    factor3 = factor3 * E3;
    factor4 = factor4 * E4;
    factor5 = factor5 * E5;
    factor6 = factor6 * E6;
run;
```

As you can see this does not seem to be a very direct way of accomplishing my task. Can anyone here help me fix this up nicely? Is it even possible?

Comment: One suggestion: Don't reuse names like this.  You risk something happening to the data where some error happens and it doesn't replace your dataset, and you don't notice.  I never like to see `data <name>; set <name>;` or `proc transpose` that goes out to the same dataset name for this reason.  It's easier to track down errors when you always make a new name - even `MyData1`, or `EigenVal_t` for transposed, and sometimes easier to troubleshoot issues also.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, obviously this isn't my real code – I just wanted to make it as simple as possible for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely could combine it more efficiently; at minimum, you can simplify the last datastep.

```
data mydata;
if _n_=1 then set MyEigenVals;
set mydata;
array factor[6];
array Eigenval[6];
do _i = 1 to dim(factor);
  factor[_i] = factor[_i]*eigenval[_i];
end;
run;
```

`SET` automatically retains variables.

Secondly, you may be able to skip the multiplication depending on how you're using the results.  You might be able to use a `weight` statement to use the eigenvalues as weights - depending on what procedures you're using to later analyze the data.  I don't know if that buys you much, but it could save you from modifying the original value which might be preferable.